# display textbox when item is selected from dropdown list html php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
 <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">
                <span class="red">*</span>Camera name</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <select name="cam_name" class="span3" id = "ddlPassport" onchange = "ShowHideDiv()">
                  <option>Select camera:</option>
                  <option>canon</option>
                  <option>nicon</option>
                  <option>sony</option>
                  <option>pentex</option>
                  <option>olympus</option>
                  <option>others</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
              <label class="control-label">Your camera name:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter model" name="cam_name" class="input-xlarge">
              </div>
            </div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowHideDiv() {
    var ddlPassport = document.getElementById("ddlPassport");
    var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
    dvPassport.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "others" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

php code

```
$camname = $_POST['cam_name'];// user name
if(empty($camname)){

      $errMSG = "Please enter camera name";

    }
```

When i select "others" from dropdown list...it works fine
but the problem is when i select canon or nicon else...the hidden div's input tag gives error..in php code when cheking with if(empty($camname));

Comment: Can you post the error message ?

Comment: Where is that php code located at? Same file as your HTML/JS or another file? And at what point of your script's runtime is that php code run at?

Comment: ya same file....problem is even though.. i selected item from dropdown list like canon,nikon,sony......the php code holds the value perfectly... but in if condition it will also checks the another input tag name="cam_name"...how to restrict it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have different names for select and input tags. And is good practice to add option values

```
<select name="cam_name" class="span3" id = "ddlPassport" onchange = "ShowHideDiv()">
<option value="">Select camera:</option>  // null
<option value="canon">canon</option>
<option value="nicon">nicon</option>
<option value="sony">sony</option>
<option value="pentex">pentex</option>
<option value="olympus">olympus</option>
<option value="others">others</option>
</select>

// give a new name for this input
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter model" name="other_cam_name" class="input-xlarge">
```

PHP code:

```
 $camname = $_POST['cam_name'];// cam name
 $other_camname = $_POST['other_cam_name'];// other cam name
 // if both select and input values 
 if(empty($camname) || ($camname =='others' && empty($other_camname))){
    echo $errMSG = "Please enter camera name";
 }else{
    echo $cam_name =  ($camname =='others') ?  $other_camname : $camname;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly define the [option](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp) values.  For example:

```
<option value="cannon">canon</option>
```